# Full text search in iOS application bundle files

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How would I go about doing a full text search across a bunch of html files in an iOS application bundle?  I need to have a lot of web content available offline and I need to be able to do a full text search across all of it.  I feel like storing that content in a database will get a little bulky and slow things down significantly.

Thoughts?

--
Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: How does xpath do full text?  The only xpath stuff I'm finding through google is xml parsing.

Comment: i hope it ll be useful for html parsing also

Comment: I'm finding some stuff about lucene kit ported to Objective C.  This is an older post http://vafer.org/blog/20090107014544/ but it mentions getting lucene kit working for the Mac OS and iPhone.  I can't find the iPhone example in the repository, seems to only be OSX.  Has anyone seen anything about an update to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do keep in mind that, even though it's a mobile device, the iPhone does have a fairly fast processor. All you're doing [said tongue-in-cheek] is searching text. These devices are built for video, music, and images.

In order of increasing amounts of coding on your part, you can:

- Use a 3rd-party library (the only one I found is Locayta)
- Port a non-Objective C search library (such as Lucene)
- Store your HTML files in a database, and do a SQL search for any search text. Without a bunch of extra coding, this will really only work easily with exact matching on a single search term.
- Manually load each file into the app and search the text using NSString's rangeOfString. Add features at will.
- Build your own search engine, built off (at least) an index of terms. Start by trimming stop words, stem if you feel the need, decide if you want document relevance or not and possibly pursue vector space algorithms. Adding in autocorrect is probably beyond your app's focus, but nonetheless building your own text search engine would be a fast (run-time) way of providing multi-word search *and* a big bullet on your resume.

Comment: Locayta is absolutely fantastic.  Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone have a cost on the commercial license for this?

Comment: looks like its 1k one-time cost per app.http://www.locayta.com/iOS-search-engine/locayta-search-mobile/ (bottom right)